# How to pass integer value between activities using intent ?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've done the coding as below...

### Activity1

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("R", num);
    startActivity(intent);
```

### Activity 2

```
v=getIntent().getIntExtra("R",2);
```

the value v should be passed to a switch.. v has 4 values...
But value of v is not changing.. always the same.. anything wrong about code ?

Comment: v=getIntent().getIntExtra("R");

Comment: you want to see changes in activity1?

Comment: when you call

startActivity(intent); before log num value can see what is.

Comment: @hakiko that didnt work

Answer (score 1):

In Activity 1:-

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("R", "anyvalue");
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity2:-

```
Public String r;
```

in OnCreate()

```
  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    r = b.getString("R");
```

Then again use Intent on Button click

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
intent.putExtra("rr", r);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity3 :-

```
 Public String s;
```

in onCreate()

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    s = b.getString("rr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity1:

    Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("R",String.valueOf(num));
    startActivity(intent);

Activity 2:

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    v= Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("R"));
```

Comment: no error but , I think value is not passing to switch... How do I check that ?

Comment: use sysout to print the num value before start intent

Answer (score 0):

**Activity 1**

```
String numstr=num.toString();
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    intent.putExtra("R", numstr);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity 2**

```
String vstr=getIntent().getExtras().getString("R");
int v=Integer.parseInt(vstr);
```

The logic here is simple.Just convert the integer to string and pass it.Then on the other class recieve it as string and then convert it into integet using parseInt().

Answer (score 0):

In Acitvity 1

```
Intent pass = new Intent(Activity2.this);
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("pos", position);
            pass.putExtras(data);
            startActivity(pass);
```

In Activity 2 in your on create method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null){

        position = extras.getInt("pos", position);  

        }
```